# Элегантная замена IF ... THEN

Tags: delphi

Есть большой список объектов, над каждым объектом пользователь может выполнять разные действия.

1. Объект А - может читать, удалять, редактировать
2. Объект Б - может читать, редактировать
3. Объект С - только просмотр.

и т.д.
На форме есть кнопки, которые должны активироваться в зависимости от прав на данный объект.

```
  // Класс объекта
  TBuilding = class(TRootClass)
  private
    ....
    // Object Accesses
    FCanRead: boolean;
    FCanEdit: boolean;
    FCanDelete: boolean;
    function GetCanDelete: boolean;
    function GetCanEdit: boolean;
    function GetCanRead: boolean;
  public
    ....
    property CanRead: boolean read GetCanRead;
    property CanEdit: boolean read GetCanEdit;
    property CanDelete: boolean read GetCanDelete;
```

Собственно, вместо IF ... THEN приходит на ум реализация примерно следующего

```
...
 procedure TObjectViewer.StringGrid1CellClick(const Column: TColumn;
  const Row: Integer);
 begin
    // DoSomething
     BEditObject.Enabled := Building.CanEdit;
     BtnDeleteObject.Enabled := Building.CanDelete;
 end;
...
```

В данном примере прав достаточно мало, однако есть другие сущности в которых их в 3 а то и 4 раза больше. Как вы бы подошли к решению данного вопроса?

Comment: *"вместо IF ... THEN"* - из вопроса совершенно непонятно, где и для чего оно вам понадобилось и  что с ними было не так. *"как вы бы подошли к решению данного вопроса"* - ¿Какого вопроса? В вашем вопросе отсутствует вопрос. Показан только кусок класса и какой-то метод с двумя присваиваниями, и все. *"узнать мнения со стороны"* - такие вопроса на данном ресурсе являются оффтопиком

Comment: @user7860670 IF .. Then в месте присваивания, из разряда `If Building.CanEdit Then BtnEditObject.Enabled  :=  True ` и т.д. В примере указана часть кода в связи с чем я сделал пометку о том что на других сущностях прав может быть в разы больше из за чего структура указанная в текущем комментарии с использованием IF может быть в разы больше и затруднит чтение кода. Возможно я действительно некорректно поставил вопрос, основная его суть - правильно ли я подошел к тому, что избавился от ветвления путем прямого присваивания состояния кнопке.

Comment: И в чём проблема?  У вас 20 кнопок, и приходится каждую отдельно запрещать/разрешать?

Comment: @ESkri совершенно верно, кнопок может быть как 3 так и 10, 15, 20 и в зависимости от прав они должны быть либо доступны, либо запрещены.

Comment: ну, придётся каждую присваивать )))  если несколько кнопок имеют одинаковое Enabled, то можно упростить код, привязав к кнопкам TAction

Comment: Я бы задействовал енумы и сеты. Что-то типа `fAllowedActions: TMyActionSet; ... Result := (aRequestedActions * fAllowedActions = aRequestedActions); ... btnSomething.Enabled := Building.CanDo([canEdit, canDelete, canRotate]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У всех контролов в Delphi есть свойство Tag, можно воспользоваться им.

1. Создаёте перечислимый тип, содержащий все возможные разрешения, с явно заданными числовыми значениями отличными от нуля, например, `type TRight = (canRead = 1, canEdit = 2, …);`
2. У объекта создаёте метод, возвращающий булево значение разрешению, например, `function CanDo(ARight: TRight): Boolean;`. Можно заменить на свойство-массив.
3. Всем кнопкам задаёте значение поля Tag равным соответствующему разрешению.
4. В цикле перебираете все контролы формы/панели, если тэг не 0, то присваиваете его свойству `Enabled` значение функции `CanDo`:

```
for i := 0 to MyForm.ControlCount - 1 do
  if MyForm.Controld[i].Tag > 0 then
    MyForm.Controld[i].Enadbled := Building.CanDo(TRight(MyForm.Controld[i].Tag));
```